# java Collections max signature

Tags: java, generics

This is the signature of `max()` in `Collections` class  :

```
public static <T extends Object & Comparable<? super T>> T max(Collection<? extends T> coll)
```

what i want to know is , why does `T` has a explicit upper bound `Object` , when `Object` is already the super type for all types.